# chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I'm doing an extension for Firefox and I pick up the call to the URL, as I can capture the http request in firefox, when running a call to a URL.

For example in google chrome on the event: chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plain `XMLHttpRequest`, which, when run from some chrome-privileged (system principal) place, allows to access all resources without obeying the same-origin policy, just like the SDK `request` module does not obey it.

- SDK: in a lib/ module get it via

  ```
  const {XMLHttpRequest} = require("sdk/net/xhr");
  ```
- XUL overlays/windows, ChromeWorker: There already is a global `XMLHttpRequest` constructor.
- JS code modules, etc:

  ```
  Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].
    createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
  ```

From there you can use `onreadystatechange` to look for a `.readyState` of `HEADERS_RECEIVED`. See the [XMLHttpRequest docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

To get cookies working for users with Deny Third-Party-Cookies you'll need to use [`forceAllowThirdPartyCookie`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/net/xhr.js) in the SDK or otherwise:

```
if (xhr_instance.channel instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannelInternal)
  xhr_instance.channel.forceAllowThirdPartyCookie = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.